# Can I apply to a large game studio if I know Unity?

Tags: unity, hiring

I'm a Unity Developer (intermediate)

I want to know, can I apply to a company like EA or Ubisoft if I know Unity, and don't switch from Unity to Unreal or any other game engine?

Comment: Of course you can apply. I think the question you meant to ask is if they would take you :)

Comment: I work at Ubisoft Toronto, so I'd be happy to discuss my experience with you ([you can DM me on Twitter](http://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory) if I'm not on [chat]). It may be relevant to add to your question what kind of role you'd like to work in. Most large studios are very specialized, with stronger delineations between designers, artists, programmers, or even specialists within each of these, than we often see in indie or smaller studios. A graphics programmer role will ask for different background and expertise than a monetization designer, for example. ;)

Comment: DMgregory man i love u :) you always correct my mistakes:)

Answer (score 3):

Most of these large game companies have multiple development teams all around the world who work with all kinds of different technology stacks.

Ubisoft, for example, [currently has a couple job openings for Unity developers](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-US/careers/search.aspx?jobFamily=programming). EA itself is mostly a publisher who does little game development themselves. But the studios owned by EA [have job openings for developers](https://www.ea.com/careers/careers-overview/worldwide-studios#PC). I haven't checked them all, but it wouldn't surprise me if some of them use Unity.

However, many of the AAA flagship titles are developed using inhouse engines you won't be able to teach yourself. But nobody else who applies to these companies is able to do this either, so they won't expect you to know their inhouse engine. So what they are looking for are people who are able to teach themselves new technologies quickly. If your career goal is to work in AAA game development, you should aim to become a holistic programmer who dives into all kinds of tech stacks, not an expert for one specific engine.